# Check if a binary tree is balanced with iterative function?

Tags: binary-tree

I need to implement a **non-recursive** function to determine if a binary tree is balanced or not.

Anyone?

Thanks!!!

Comment: What have you tried? What kind of balance you are looking for? How efficient it needs to be?

Comment: Your question really doesn't give anyone enough information to give you an answer. What have you tried? What language are you using? This wouldn't be a homework question, would it?...

Comment: @Floris whenever language isn't given, I assume `language-agnostic` `algorithm`

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that by "balanced", you mean "height-balanced" in the AVL-tree sense, and you can store arbitrary information for each node,

- For each node in post-order,

  - if either child doesn't exist, assume its respective height is 0.
  - if the height of both children differs by more than one, the tree is not balanced.
  - otherwise, this node's height is the larger of both children's heights.
- If this point is reached, the tree is balanced.

One way to perform post-order traversal:

- start at the root
- loop

  - if this node's left child exists and does not have its height computed, visit its left child next.
  - else if this node's right child exists and does not have its height computed, visit its right child next.
  - else

    - compute this node's height, possibly returning early
    - if this node is not the root, visit its parent next.
- If this point is reached, the tree is balanced.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the accurate answer. Yes I meant height-balanced. Where could I find the implementation of this function in c++?

Comment: @user2000916 you could write one. Concerning some implementation details - you could store the depth as two variables (visited / unvisited, depth) or as one (depth if visited, 0 if unvisited)

Comment: Basically I need an iterative version of this implementation: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-determine-if-a-binary-tree-is-balanced/

Comment: @user2000916 do you think you can convince me to write your homework? My pseudo-code translates directly to C++, and your source shows how to write C++ code. Do some work, man.

Comment: Does your implementation change if my node structure can contain only an int, a pointer to the left child, a pointer to the right child?

Comment: @user2000916 then you can implement `go left` as `push the current node to stack; go left` and `go up` as `pop the stack as the current node`

Comment: What if I first calculate and store somewhere the depth of each leaf. Then if the depths are all the same or differs by 1 at most the tree is balanced, unbalanced otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public class BalancedBinaryTree {
    public static class TreeNode {
        int val;
        TreeNode left;
        TreeNode right;
        TreeNode() {}
        TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
        TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
            this.val = val;
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }
    }

    public boolean isBalanced(TreeNode root) {
        if (root==null) {
             return true;
        }
        Stack<TreeNode> stack = new Stack<>();
        Map<TreeNode, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        stack.push(root);
        while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
            TreeNode node = stack.pop();
            if ((node.left==null || (node.left!=null && map.containsKey(node.left))) && (node.right==null || (node.right!=null && map.containsKey(node.right)))) {
                int right = (node.right==null) ? 0 : map.get(node.right);
                int left = (node.left==null) ? 0 : map.get(node.left);
                if (Math.abs(right-left)>1) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    map.put(node, Math.max(right, left)+1);
                }
            } else {
                if (node.left!=null && !map.containsKey(node.left)) {
                    stack.push(node);
                    stack.push(node.left);
                } else {
                    stack.push(node);
                    stack.push(node.right);
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BalancedBinaryTree b = new BalancedBinaryTree();
        boolean v = b.isBalanced(new TreeNode(3, new TreeNode(9), new TreeNode(20, new TreeNode(15), new TreeNode(7))));
        System.out.println(v);
        v = b.isBalanced(new TreeNode(1, new TreeNode(2, new TreeNode(3, new TreeNode(4), new TreeNode(4)), new TreeNode(3)), new TreeNode(2)));
        System.out.println(v);
        v = b.isBalanced(new TreeNode(1, new TreeNode(2, new TreeNode(4, new TreeNode(8), null), new TreeNode(5)), new TreeNode(3, new TreeNode(6), null)));
        System.out.println(v);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a c++ code that works, inspired by the postorder traversal. The code is not commented because i do not think a simple comment is enough to explain the whole algorithm. You can execute this code manually with the example below and then you will understand everything.

```cpp
bool IsBalance(const Node *head)
{
    std::stack<const Node *> s;
    std::stack<int> sV;
    const Node *curr = head, *lastVisit = nullptr;
    int deep = 0;
    while (curr || !s.empty())
    {
        while (curr)
        {
            s.push(curr);
            sV.push(-1);
            curr = curr->m_pLeft;
        }

        curr = s.top();
        if (sV.top() == -1)
        {
            sV.top() = deep;
        }

        if (!curr->m_pRight || curr->m_pRight == lastVisit)
        {
            if (!curr->m_pRight)
            {
                deep = 0;
            }
            if (std::abs(sV.top() - deep) > 1)
            {
                return false;
            }
            deep = std::max(sV.top(), deep) + 1;
            lastVisit = curr;
            s.pop();
            sV.pop();
            curr = nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            deep = 0;
            curr = curr->m_pRight;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

examples:

```bash
(1) 21,10,3,1,#,#,5,#,6,#,#,15,12,#,#,18,16,#,#,20,#,#,35,30,22,#,#,#,40,36,#,#,42,#,45,#,#
(2) 1,2,#,4,#,5,#,#,3,6,8,#,#,#,7,#,#
(3) 3,1,#,2,#,#,#
```

Where nodes are arranged by PreOrder, separated by commas, and # indicates an empty node.

Answer (score 0):

Find the height of left subtree and right subtree for a node of the tree, using Level order traversal and check if that node is balanced.
Repeat this for every node of the tree. For traversing all the nodes we can use level order traversal to avoid recursion.

```
int height(TreeNode* root){
        if(!root){
            return 0;
        }
        queue<TreeNode*> q;
        q.push(root);
        int count=0;
        while(!q.empty()){
            int size=q.size();
            for(int i=0;i<size;++i){
                TreeNode* temp=q.front();
                q.pop();
                if(temp->left){
                    q.push(temp->left);
                }
                if(temp->right){
                    q.push(temp->right);
                }
            }
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
    bool checkEveryNode(TreeNode* root){
        if(!root){
            return true;
        }
       queue<TreeNode*> q;
        q.push(root);
        while(!q.empty()){
            int count=q.size();
            for(int i=0;i<count;++i){
                TreeNode* temp=q.front();
                q.pop();
                int left=height(temp->left);
                int right=height(temp->right);
                if(abs(left-right)>1){
                    return false;
                }
                if(temp->left){
                    q.push(temp->left);
                }
                if(temp->right){
                    q.push(temp->right);
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    bool isBalanced(TreeNode* root) {
        return checkEveryNode(root);
    }
```

Time complexity of this approach is O(n^2), as we need to traverse all the descendant nodes for finding the height of a node(N) and we need to do this for all the nodes(N)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another take on the problem, it uses a state machine during traversal to keep track of visited branches. It is more verbose than @xxllxx666's solution, but I'm hoping it may be easier to understand. There are potential microoptimizations but I keep it simple *(if you search for optimizations, @xxllxx666's solution may suit better)*.

Approach: we always traverse left nodes first, and right ones second. We traverse left nodes and add them to the `tree` vector till we reach the bottom. At that point we set the node's depth to `0` and change state to `LeftCalculated`. Then we look on the right side *(again, traversing left-first if there're more left nodes)*. Once the right side is processed as well, we change node's state to `BothCalculated`, which means we can drop the current node and process the parent one.

We also never add both child nodes to the vector at the same time. Besides being more space-efficient, that also guarantees that `i-1` node in the vector is always the parent of the `i`th node.

```cpp
bool isBalanced(TreeNode* root) {
    if (!root)
        return true;

    enum CalculationState {UnCalculated, LeftCalculated, BothCalculated};
    struct NodeState {
        const TreeNode *node;
        CalculationState state = UnCalculated;
        int depth = 0;
    };
    for (vector<NodeState> tree = {{root}}; tree.size(); ) {
        NodeState& curr_node = tree.back();
        switch (curr_node.state) {
            case UnCalculated: {
                for (const TreeNode* next_node = curr_node.node->left; next_node; next_node = next_node->left)
                    tree.push_back({next_node});
                NodeState& last_pushed_node = tree.back();
                last_pushed_node.state = LeftCalculated; // don't need to change depth, it's 0
                break;
            }
            case LeftCalculated: {
                if (curr_node.node->right) {
                    tree.push_back({curr_node.node->right});
                } else {
                    if (curr_node.depth > 1) // right depth is 0
                        return false;
                    curr_node.state = BothCalculated;
                }
                break;
            }
            case BothCalculated: {
                int curr_depth = curr_node.depth;
                tree.pop_back();
                if (tree.size()) {
                    NodeState& parent_node = tree.back();
                    assert(parent_node.state != BothCalculated);
                    if (parent_node.state == UnCalculated) {
                        parent_node.state = LeftCalculated;
                        parent_node.depth = curr_depth + 1;
                    } else {
                        if (std::abs(parent_node.depth - (curr_depth + 1)) > 1)
                            return false;
                        parent_node.depth = max(curr_depth + 1, parent_node.depth);
                        parent_node.state = BothCalculated;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```